# Write permission on external SD card is denied

Tags: android, adb, android-5.0-lollipop, android-sdcard, android-permissions

I use command `adb push` to transfer files to external SD card of my phone. I'm using Android 5.0. But the **write permission is denied**.

I use `ls` command to see the permissions list.

```
./adb shell ls /storage/extSdCard -la
```

And here is one of what I got:

```
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-12-13 10:29 new
```

As you see, the file group is **sdcard_r** (has no write permission). Please help me! How can I write data to external SD card using adb?

Answer (score 0):

Root itself is just a user with elevated permissions, who can do anything to any file or folder in the system. It's often dangerous, always powerful, and an integral part of Linux. Android is the most popular "version" of Linux in the world (as well as the most popular computing system), but as we discussed above superuser access is more restricted than it is on other Linux systems

root your phone

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The main reason is I don't want to root my phone.